# Building RS485 serial to USB adapter with digispark

Tags: serial, usb, raspberrypi, rs485, digispark

Is it possible to build an serial-adapter with digispark board?
Like: Embedded System with 2-wire RS-485 Port connect to my digispark board. Digispark Board is connected via USB to my Computer (running Linux tty or Windows COM Putty Interface)

I also own a Raspberry Pi. I'm very new at this thing, so maybe there is a way to convert the RS485 signals to monitoring my devices with my computer?

Comment: Yes. However; you state that you are 'very new at this thing', you may want to start with blinking LED's and/or find a tutorial for what project you're thinking off; so you can follow along easily.

Comment: I just started with coding digispark, like with these blink led or some other things, but ich dont know where to find the right keyword or tutorial with this serial COM connectors.

Answer (score 1):

There are some good books available to help. There is the Raspberry Pi cookbook and the Arduino cookbook. These will take you from the very beginning to the point where you can make your own designs and they will work.

Answer (score 0):

I would steer you away from using something that has a chip with neither a USART nor USB hardware for the purposes of making something like that. The ATTiny85 that's on the Digispark has USI (Universal Serial Interface), which is really more of a USART construction kit. The USB support it has is bitbanged and somewhat unreliable.

If you do go in this direction and want a small Arduino type board like Digispark, the "Beetle" ATMega32u4 based boards are a better choice.  It has a native USB interface, and a proper USART to hook to an RS-485 driver.

The chip also has a bootloader section; it is difficult to corrupt your own sketch.  It also has more memory, not that you necessarily need it.